# Type mismatch in VBA, cant do operations with Cells(x,x).Value

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to write a macro to calculate some relative values. I basically go though the entire colum, take some values and divide it by another one and write in another column. That procedure is not relevant. What is bugging me is that I get a type mismatch in hold3=hold/hold2. I broke down like that (using the hold, hold2,hold3) to see where the problem is. It is in the division. If I just leave hold3=hold it doesnt give me an error. When I try to divide or sum or do any operations, it gives me the mismatch error. I tried declaring all variables as double, not using any variables at all (going for Cells(i,8).Value = Cells(i,7).Value/Cells(cuenta,7) ) and nothing works.

```
Sub DivideByTotal()  
Dim innerTop As Long
Dim counter As Long

Dim hold As Variant
Dim hold2 As Variant
Dim hold3 As Variant


For counter = 9 To 559
    innerTop = counter + 4
    Dim i As Long
    For i = counter To innerTop
        Dim cuenta As Long
        cuenta = counter
        hold = Cells(i, 7).Value
        hold2 = Cells(cuenta, 7).Value
        hold3 = hold / hold2
        Cells(i, 8).Value = hold3
    Next i
    counter = counter + 4
Next counter
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Debug.Print hold` and `Debug.Print hold2` to check what's the values you're using to do the division. You can also use `msgbox hold` and `msgbox hold2` for the same.

Comment: if you have a blank cell you're going to get this error when using variants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub DivideByTotal()

Dim innerTop As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim hold As Double
Dim hold2 As Double
Dim hold3 As Double
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim cuenta As Long    

Set wk=Sheet1   'Replace it with the sheet number

With wk
For counter = 9 To 559
    innerTop = counter + 4

    For i = counter To innerTop
        cuenta = counter
        hold = .Cells(i, 7).Value
        hold2 = .Cells(cuenta, 7).Value
        if Isnumeric(hold)=0 or isnumeric(hold2)=0 then  'Check if hold and hold2 are numbers or not.
              Debug.Print hold
              Debug.Print hold2
        ELse 
            hold3 = hold / hold2
            .Cells(i, 8).Value = hold3
        End if
    Next i
    counter = counter + 4

Next counter
End With

End Sub
```